# Передать значение $_SERVER одного домена в другой домен

Tags: php

У меня получается получить значении таким образом (работаю c разными доменами):

`https://site1.ru`:

```
$output = include_once('https://site2.ru/script.php');
```

Но не получается, если попытаться передать значение доменной имени первого сайта во вторую, так:

`https://site2.ru`:

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
```

В итоге все равно получаю `site2.ru`, а хочу получить `site1.ru`

Код пробовал переделать так:

`https://site1.ru`:

```
$domen = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$output = include_once('https://site2.ru/script.php');
```

`https://site2.ru`:

```
echo $output;
```

думал что переменный $domen передаст значение в include_once (это понятно, с целью защиты).

Как нужно было делать правильно?

Comment: Если честно из вопроса ничего не понятно, поясните более конкретно

Comment: Из сайта site1 хочу передать значение $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; в сайт site2, а затем с помощью include_once вывести в site1 (мне обязательно нужно передать в site2, точнее в его обработчик название домена site1, как переменный, чтобы в дальнейшем выполнить с ним какое-либо действие)

Comment: @Ilnyr а почему не использовать `GET` или `POST` запросы?

Comment: Я могу использовать ajax например. Выходит таким образом: site1: <?php $domenprep = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; ?><script>$.post("site2/script.php",{domen:"<?php echo $domen; ?>"}</script> в site2 прописываю это: $domen = $_POST["domen"]; Больше нет чтоли вариантов, кроме этого?

Answer (score 0):

Если оба сайта ваши, то можно сделать так:

**site2.ru/script.php**

```
<?php
echo json_encode($_SERVER);
```

А потом на **https://­​site1.­​ru**:

```
<?php
$SITE2_SERVER = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://site2.ru/script.php"), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если руками отправлять, то содержимое  **site1.­​ru**:

```
<form method="get" action="site2.ru/script.php">
<input type="hidden" name="host" value="<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Содержимое **site2.ru/script.php**:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['host']) && !empty($_GET['host'])) echo $_GET['host'];
```

Или можно использовать что-то из этого:
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/